# Custom hook to await callback from useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a web application, iwth an instance of a keycloack.js, where i tried to use a custom hook, to fetch a userprofile, before the UI renders. 
The reason for that, is that the actual application requires, some information in localStorage before the ui should render.

Here is the logic i have tried to implement in my `App.js` component

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'appkit-react/style/appkit-react.default.css';
import PageHub from './Components/Navigation/PageHub';
import Spinner from './Components/Shared/Spinner';
import LoadUserProfile from './_helpers/hooks/loadUserProfile'
import './i18n';

function App(props) {


  const [loading, error] = LoadUserProfile(props.keycloak)
  console.log(props)
  if(loading){
    return <Spinner />
  }
  if(error){
    console.log(error)
    return <div>Error occured!!</div>
  }
  console.log(loading)
  console.log(error)
  return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
        <PageHub/>
      </Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the `LoadUserProfile` hook looks like this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Spinner from '../../Components/Shared/Spinner';

function LoadUserProfile(keycloak){
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState({});

    useEffect(() =>{
        setLoading(true)
        keycloak.loadUserProfile().success((profile) => {
            console.debug('Loaded profile ' + profile);
            localStorage.setItem("firstName", keycloak.profile.firstName);
            localStorage.setItem("lastName", keycloak.profile.lastName);
            localStorage.setItem('GUID', keycloak.profile.attributes.guid[0])
            setLoading(false)
        }).error(() => {
            console.error('Failed to load profile')
            setLoading(false)
            setError({"error": "No user found"})
        }, [keycloak, loading, error]);

    })


    return [loading, error]

}
export default LoadUserProfile;
```

right now it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: deleted my answer again due to there are several problems with your code. 1. You may not call the setLoading and setError functions inside your useEffect. Any changes here will lead to a rerender (because those functions will set a new state) where useEffect will be called again; 2. Don't make use of hooks inside of nested functions; 3. better use a parent's component state or a context (or even redux) to store your data instead of `localStorage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you must rename your custom hook to **useLoadUserProfile** as recommended in the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) so that React would be able to automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks. The infinite loop is caused by the inclusion of the **loading** and **error** states in your dependency array.
Whenever you make a call to 'setMyState' in this case **setLoading** or **setError**

1. React reruns your custom hook again and returns updated **loading** or **error** states
2. The useEffect hook is then run again and calls **setLoading** or **setError** which causes React to run your function again.... hence the infinite loop.

So to fix this you must remove the **loading** and **error** states from your dependency array. The Rule of thumb is:
 ***if you specify the dependency array, all values from inside your component that are used by the effect must be there. Including props, state, functions — anything in your component.*** i.e never lie about your dependencies.

In your case your useEffect hook does not even depend on your **loading** or **error** states. So they shouldn't be in the dependency array in the first place!